# Does atomic time slow down at faster speeds?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

Continuing with my questioning regarding two different "times", (but hopefully within the scope inquiry this time), if two asteroids are in an orbit around the solar system, one at 10,000kph and another at 1,000,000kph (100 times faster), relativity says that time relative to each other will be different.

Lets further say that they each contain 2 tons of Uranium 238.

Ignoring external forces and using only time dilation, will each asteroid have the same amount of after uranium 238 after 10,000 Earth years?

Comment: BTW, Earth's mean orbital speed is ~107,000 km/h. So your fast asteroid has a mean orbital radius of ~0.01 au or ~1.5 million km, which is rather close to the Sun. Your slow asteroid is at ~100 au.

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks for that information. I should have left speeds out of it since they really don't matter as long as they are considerably different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will each asteroid have the same amount of uranium 238 after 10,000 Earth years?

No. Time dilation affects the rate of radioactive decay and other particle decay rates. This has been experimentally verified in many experiments, starting in the 1940s with the measurement of the lifetimes of relativistic muons created when cosmic rays interact with the upper atmosphere. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_testing_of_time_dilation) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Given the words you used I searched and found a duplicate. I voted to close this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do the experiment with uranium, but much easier with things that are shorter-lived and move faster. At Earth's surface, the majority of secondary cosmic ray particles are muons, radioactive particles with a half life of 1.56 µs. They move at nearly the speed of light: in 1.56 µs, they move about 450 meters. But they are produced in the atmosphere at altitudes >10 km, so if not for time dilation, very few should reach the surface. Yet many do, so we may conclude that time dilation affects radioactive "clocks". This is confirmed by more quantitative studies of cosmic rays and the products of particle accelerator collisions.